# put two edittext vertically by a special distance in android studio

Tags: android

I am new in Android and I want to put two EditText vertically but one of them cover other and when I changed padding-top or margin-top second one it was not useful. How can I solve this problem?

I think it does not need code and just by setting a property it will be solve but this is the code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/activity_main"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context="">

   <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

       <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText" />


<Button
    android:text="Add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn_AddData"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_AddData"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/listview_lv" />
```

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Comment: show your code..

Comment: @intelliJ Amiya I think it should have a easy way like other developer software just by changing some properties. so I changed margin-top to 20px but in preview edittext disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
android:layoutHeight="match_parent"
android:layoutWidth="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
android:layoutHeight="match_parent"
android:layoutWidth="match_parent"/>

<EditText
android:marginTop="10sp"
android:layoutHeight="match_parent"
android:layoutWidth="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please go through android layout. You must be using relative layout where one components depends on the position of another one. I just have shown using linearlayout. You can use others layout too. Here **orientation** is the major factor.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" />


<Button
    android:text="Add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn_AddData"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_AddData"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/listview_lv" />
</RelativeLayout>
```